# What is setuid based script root spoofing?

Tags: spoofing

I'm reading [this](http://linux-training.be/files/books/html/fun/ch19s08.html) and I'm little confused. What exactly is this setuid based script root spoofing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a theoretical attack that could allow a user to elevate their privileges to root.

Say we have a setuid-root `script.sh` like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Hello World!
```

When the script is executed, the OS reads the first line, the uses that program to run the script. The command it will execute is: `/bin/bash script.sh`

A twist on setuid scripts is that a user can create a link to the script, say `myscript.sh`
and now the command would be `/bin/bash myscript.sh` This is starting to be a bit worrying because perhaps the user could call their link `-c ls` - and run a command as root that they're not supposed to.

However, bash and Linux have a number of other defences that make this impractical. For example, the command on Linux would be `/bin/bash "./-c ls"` which is not exploitable. It's possible that other shells and OS are vulnerable.

All of this only applies if you have a setuid-root shell script. This is not recommended anyway - for these reasons and more. In fact, on Linux you can't have setuid shell scripts at all.

If you're interested in this area in general, [Nebula](http://exploit-exercises.com/nebula) is worth a look.